# How to update JSONB column using exising data in postgres table

Tags: json, postgresql

I have an existing table with fields that I want to parse into a JSON object and then update an existing column with the JSON object.

Here is what I would like to be able to do (note: all values in JSON object are values currently in the table):

```
update table_name
set json_object = {"id": note_id, "attribute": sentence}
where note_id = 12345
```

I know this would not work and that I need to use the function `jsonb_set` (or similar method), but all examples I've found do NOT use existing columns/fields from the table in question to build the JSON object.

Comment: `set json_object = jsonb_build_object('id', note_id, 'attribute': sentence)`

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, I did not find this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any expression, including column references, as arguments to `jsonb_set`. That might look like

```
UPDATE table_name
SET json_object = jsonb_set(jsonb_set(json_object, '{id}', note_id), '{attribute}', sentence)
WHERE note_id = 12345;
```

That sets the two properties on the existing `json_object` value. Notice that `path` parameter is a `text` array (`text[]`), you could also write `ARRAY['id']` if you prefer.

If instead of updating the existing value, you want to overwrite it with a fresh object, you could use `jsonb_set('{}', …)` but that's cumbersome. You'd rather use `jsonb_build_object` which is a variadic function taking key-value pairs, so you'd write

```
UPDATE table_name
SET json_object = jsonb_build_object('id', note_id, 'attribute': sentence)
WHERE note_id = 12345;
```

This is sometimes also used for updating, by merging the new object into the existing value via the `||` operator, to avoid deeply nested `jsonb_set` expressions for many properties:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET json_object = json_object || jsonb_build_object('id', note_id, 'attribute': sentence)
WHERE note_id = 12345;
```